# Obter dados de um ficheiro XML, usando XPath e C#

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

Tenho o seguinte documento `XML`, e pretendo fazer uma pesquisa/filtro por nome ***GivenName*** usando `Xpath`. Como fazer?

## XML

```
<bloodonors>
  <donor>
    <Number>1</Number>
    <Gender>male</Gender>
    <GivenName>Estevan</GivenName>
    <Surname>Rodrigues</Surname>
  </donor>
  <donor>
    <Number>2</Number>
    <Gender>female</Gender>
    <GivenName>Lucy</GivenName>
    <Surname>Silva</Surname>
  </donor>
  <donor>
    <Number>3</Number>
    <Gender>female</Gender>
    <GivenName>Beatriz</GivenName>
    <Surname>Santos</Surname>
  </donor>
</bloodonors>
```

## Meu código

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(@ "Dadores.xml");
XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement; //seleciona elemento do documento
XmlNodeList listaDador = root.SelectNodes("/bloodonors/donor[GivenName[contains(.,'" + GivenName + "'0] or Surname[contains(.,'" + Surname + "'0]");
```

Comment: Relacionado em inglês: [Extracting an XML element from an XML file using XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444809/extracting-an-xml-element-from-an-xml-file-using-xpath)

Comment: O que já tentou ? Quais erros estão aparecendo ?

Comment: Tentei usar SelectNodes, mas não estou a conseguir, já procurei na web, e não encontrei nada, este é o meu último recurso

Comment: @Blazin posta o código em C# que tentou!

Comment: p.s - não sou muito bom a programar, comecei a pouco tempo, daí precisar de ajuda projecto

Comment: @Marconi já coloquei na pergunta o código que tentei usar

Comment: @Blazin no começo é assim mesmo, vou tentar te ajudar por aqui se não aparecer uma resposta bem provável que posto uma! Seja bem vindo ao Stack overflow, recomendo a leitura no [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender um pouco mais como funcionam as coisas por aqui.

Comment: @Blazin adicionei uma resposta!

Comment: @Blazin caso a resposta do Marconi resolva seu problema, marque-a como aceita/correta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## [Método XmlNode.SelectNodes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/hcebdtae(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Seleciona uma lista de nós que correspondem à expressão XPath.

Seu código deve estar assim:

```
 XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
 doc.Load("EnderecoArquivo");
 XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement; //seleciona elemento do documento
 XmlNodeList listaDador = root.SelectNodes("//donor[contains(GivenName,'Este')]");
 List < XmlNode > listOfNodes = new List < XmlNode > (listaDador.Cast < XmlNode > ());

 listOfNodes.ForEach(i => Console.WriteLine(i.InnerXml));
```

Resultado:

```
<Number>1</Number><Gender>male</Gender><GivenName>Estevan</GivenName><Surname>Rodrigues</Surname>
```